# Promisify Redis client

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, promise, bluebird

How can I `promisify redis` so that I could use `then`?

I have tried to promisify client:

```
var redis = require('redis');
Promise.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
var client  = redis.createClient();

client.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('Redis connection is up');

    client.lrange('abc',0,3).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        res.send(200)
    });
});
```

But it responds with error:

> client.lrange(...).then is not a function

PS: The callback code works fine, so it means server is running perfectly.

Comment: `lrange` does have _4th_ argument as `callback`, why you are not using that ?

Comment: because I am trying to use promise

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using `promisifyAll`, the promisified methods get an `-Async` suffix:

```
client.lrangeAsync('abc',0,3).then(...);
```

As per [the documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html):

> Note that the original methods on the object are not overwritten but new methods are created with the `Async`-suffix. For example, if you `promisifyAll` the node.js `fs` object use `fs.statAsync` to call the promisified `stat` method.

Comment: [__`Promise.promisifyAll`__](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) itself has example of `redis`, I am amazed OP could not figure that out.. +1

Comment: upvoted! how does this work with client.multi().get("test").exec((err, callback) => {})